# Dump network traffic of single application (strace-like)

Tags: networking, dump

I'm looking for a way to dump pcap of network data generated by an application, in a simmilar way `strace` dumps syscalls, etc. eg:

```
net-strace somecommand -args
```

`somecommand` would do something over the network, and `net-strace` would save a pcap dump of all the traffic generated by that app (+ replies and related traffic).

Can this be achieved?

Comment: The problem is that applications don't send packets (except those using raw sockets like ping) but use a networking API that causes the kernel to send packets (and receive related one) on their behalf.

Comment: Yes, but there are applications (eg proxychains - http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/ ) which run all application data through a proxy. Don't know how they do it, but they can capture it and send it through a proxy. Maybe if there is a simple proxy (run locally), which can dump pcap, proxychains+proxy combo can be used for obtaining the dump.

Comment: They're are more likely hijacking the API (with LD_PRELOAD) than the packets. Having said that, one might be able to inject some setsockopt(SO_MARK) into applications and use netfilter to log the packets to ulog.

Comment: Create a new network namespace for the application and capture all traffic in there may be an acceptable approach for some use cases as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about using strace itself?

```
strace -f -e trace=network -o output_file -s 10000 somecommand -args
```

Comment: The command line you gave appears to only show DNS requests. strace's `-e` option frequently doesn't select what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

You may dump application generated traffic by different methods:

If you know the ports the application is using, you can run *tcpdump* or *wireshark* with specific filtering rules for these ports.

If that is not an option, you may mark application packets using an *iptables* rule, matching the owner of the process. You may need to create a new user account to completely isolate the process. Then you can capture the traffic that only matches the rule.

You may find more complete information on this related topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11709/how-can-i-capture-network-traffic-of-a-single-process

You may also find interesting this program *tracedump* as stated by previous topic. http://mutrics.iitis.pl/tracedump